# Encouraging new questioners to include relevant information in questions?

Tags: discussion, help-center

This Q is inspired by [Ancestors union civil war pension containing a USCT vet on their pension](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/19043/1006) but the issue applies site-wide.

Can we create a resource on the site to encourage people to include archival references or other information about the document they're looking at if they don't want to share a link to an image or a screenshot?

Using the example above, there are (if memory serves) four different series of index cards that might refer to a Civil War veteran's pension records, that were created for different purposes by the Pension Office or other federal agencies.  If someone tells me which microfilm series they are looking at, even if I don't see the exact card the person is looking at, I know what information is likely to be on the card because I am likely to have other records from that series from my own research.

Can we edit the help to ask that people include the archive reference or microfilm series or whatever specific record collection they are looking at, even if they don't want to link to the individual's own record?

Answer (score 3):

There's three ways that we can augment the help:

1. Go to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help where there is an edit button usable by moderators
2. Go to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic where there is another edit button usable by moderators
3. Create a Meta G&FH Q&A, tag it as an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and optionally link it into one or both of the places above.

Comment: I just noticed your links go to GIS.SE.  Did you mean to link to G&FH.SE's help instead?

Comment: Thanks for picking that up @JanMurphy - fixed now.